# Creating a webpart that lists files with a specified yesno column equalling yes

Tags: 2013

I am trying to create a webpart on a team site home page that lists all the documents in the site that have been marked with a 'Yes' in a new KeyDocument column.  My steps so far have been to:-

- Create a new YesNo column called KeyDocument in site settings
- Add this column to a library (I will eventually add it to all the libraries)
- Populate the column with 'Yes' in half a dozen existing documents
- Create a 'Content Search' web part in the home page

...and then I get stuck.  How do I make the web part find and list all the documents with the KeyDocument property set to 'Yes'?  The query builder doesn't seem to allow for this.

Or should I be using a different webpart?

I'm self-taught and I'm sorry if this is a basic question.  It's just got me stumped.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your new custom column to your Managed Properties (if it wasn't already automatically added).

Start by going to Site Settings and under Site Collection Administration, go to Search Schema. This will bring you to the list of your managed properties. First check if your KeyDocument property is there. If so, edit it and make sure "Queryable" is selected.

If it is not there, you need to add it.

1. On the Managed Properties page, click "New Managed Property"
2. Put in the name, "KeyDocument," and description
3. Select the property (if you set it up as a Yes/No column select Yes/No)
4. Check mark "Queryable," "Retrievable," and "Safe"
5. Go down to the mapping and click "Add a Mapping"
    
   a. Your column will appear as `ows_KeyDocument` in the list, add it
6. Click OK

SharePoint will need to perform a full crawl after this point which happens every 15-60 minutes.

After that, go to your Content Search web part and open the query box. Your new property should be in the property list. Select it and set it equal to "Yes."

Comment: I shall try that when I am next in the office.  Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: @SteveN. have had a chance to try this?